# How to set custom background image in Hyperterm

Tags: hyperterm

I am trying to switch to Hyperterm from iTerm that I am currently using. But I had a custom background image in my terminal and I'd like to keep having this in new terminal.

I found only `backgroundColor` in options so far, but nothing about background image.

Comment: Guess you figured it out yourself huh? https://github.com/zeit/hyperterm/pull/585 Are you satisfied with your solution or do you need any other help with it?

Comment: Yes, I realised, that this is not implemented. I will be satisfied when this pull request will be merged

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After [some discussion on Github](https://github.com/zeit/hyperterm/pull/585), I have found a solution. Add the following options into your config file:

```
module.exports = {
  css: `
    .terms_terms {
      background: url(file://path-to-file) center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  `,

  termCSS: `
    x-screen {
      background: transparent !important;
    }
  `
};
```

Hope it helps for somebody else.

Comment: I had to also install hyper transparent `hyper i hyper-transparent` to get the black terminal area to become transparent.

Answer (score 5):

I manage to change it using

```
// custom css to embed in the main window
css: `
  .terms_terms {
    background: url(file://<path-to-image>) center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .terms_termGroup {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) !important
  }
`
```

inside **~/hyper.js**

Using `x-screen` didnt work for we